# Inserting two tables together with no Id or UNIQUE anything

Tags: sybase, except

Let's assume we have two tables:

- #### `table1`, retaining the following data:

  ```
  Name Height Age
  ---- ------ ---
  Mary   1.60  18
  Mary   1.62  19
  Mary   1.68  20
  John   1.80  17
  John   1.85  18
  John   1.86  19
  ```
- #### `table2`, with the rows shown below:

  ```
  Name Height Age
  ---- ------ ---
  Mary   1.60  18
  Mary   1.62  19
  Mary   1.68  20
  John   1.80  17
  John   1.85  18
  John   1.86  19
  Vince  1.78  22
  Vince  1.80  23
  ```

How would I JOIN these two tables using Sybase so that afterward `table1` has Vinces data in it?

Think of `table2` as a temporary table that contains new information. I want to update `table1` with the new information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
insert into table1
select * from table2
except
select * from table1;
```

You could also use:

```
select * 
from table2 
where Name not in (select Name from table1)
```

This works too (assuming `Name` cannot be `NULL`).

The difference is that the `except` version delivers all rows that are not the same whereas the `not in` query delivers all rows where the name does not exist. Up to you to decide if this is what you need.